# Django doesn't convert the datetime using the right timezone

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, timezone, django-timezone

I'm struggling to figure out how timezone works in Django. On my systems I have all datetimes in `UTC+00` even with a `UTC+02` TIME_ZONE setting.

```
timezone.get_default_timezone()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Rome' RMT+0:50:00 STD>

timezone.get_current_timezone()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Rome' RMT+0:50:00 STD>
```

I'm using `PostgreSQL` as backend database and I'm using the following settings:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Rome'
USE_TZ = True
```

The documentations about [PostgreSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#postgresql) say:

> ... if you’re using PostgreSQL, you can switch between USE_TZ = False
>   and USE_TZ = True freely. The database connection’s time zone will be
>   set to TIME_ZONE or UTC respectively, so that Django obtains correct
>   datetimes in all cases. You don’t need to perform any data
>   conversions.

If from shell I try to get the `date_joined` field of an User, this one is UTC+00 and not converted to UTC+02 (as expected since I'm using TIME_ZONE)

```
admin.date_joined                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 12, 15, 22, 58, tzinfo=<UTC>)

str(admin.date_joined)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
'2017-07-12 15:22:58+00:00'
```

The serialized object (DRF) contain the same wrong datetime of course (in UTC+00)

```
"date_joined": "2017-07-12T15:22:58Z",
```

Django also offer the possibility to set the favorite TIME_ZONE to end user 's with activate() method, but this is a different thing. By default when I retrieve data from the database all datetimes should be converted to the relative TIME_ZONE settings right?

What I'm missing? where I get wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to understand that `datetimes` are converted to the current time zone only when ["rendering"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#default-time-zone-and-current-time-zone). That is, when using templates, forms, or, in the case of Django Rest Framework, serializers.

The timezone of the Python `datetime` object depends on the database connection, and is usually `UTC`. One reason for this is that timezones are primarily a display issue, so it doesn't really matter what the timezone of your Python object is. A more important reason is that timezone conversions are potentially lossy (since many timezones have ambiguous times around DST), so you really don't want to do this sort of conversion until the very last step.

Comment: So If I figured out the problem, is correct to have UTC+00 at DB level and each time I need to show the right datetime to end user's I need to convert it manually using for example  timezone.localtime(admin.date_joined) In a view, template or serializer

Comment: @realnot: In views (or anywhere you're dealing with Python `datetime` objects) they will be in UTC. In templates you should see the correct timezone, as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zone-aware-output-in-templates). I don't use DRF, but [the documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datetimefield) implies that you should see it in the correct timezone. It's *rare* that you would need to convert it with `localtime`, for most projects that will never be necessary.

Comment: So I have to figure out why DRF doesn't perform the conversation since I'm using `USE_TZ = True` with with `TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Rome'` configured properly!

Comment: @realnot: Agreed, that is the one unexpected result in your question.